# How can I do the same thing in multiple tabs in a web browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-tabs, tabs

I have to open a list of links in multiple tabs (e.g. in Firefox) which all have a certain button in the same position and I should click those buttons. Is there a way that I can do the thing in all tabs at the same time instead of opening each link and manually click the buttons or playing a macro in each tab?
For example, a tool that gives the ability to do an action in one tab, and the same action happen in other selected tabs simultaneously.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?